# Функция, которая меняет местами первый и последний элемент массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, циклы

Нужно реализовать функцию, которая меняет местами первый и последний элемент массива, но чтобы если массив состоит меньше, чем из двух элементов, он возвращался так как есть. Моя функция, к сожалению не работает( i это последнее число в массиве

```
    export function swap (massive) {
   for (let i = 0; i = massive.length - 1; i++) {
     let temp1;
      if (massive.length > 1) {
         temp1 = massive[0];
         massive[0] = massive[i];
         massive[i] = temp1;
         return massive;
}
  else {
    return massive;
  }
   }
}
```

Comment: *если массив состоит меньше, чем из двух элементов, он возвращался так как есть.* Наверное, проще поменять единственный элемент с самим собой (что на сам массив не влияет), чем обрабатывать этот особый случай. А вот случай, когда массив пуст, обработать нужно, чтобы не огрести ошибки выхода за пределы массива...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а зачем вам цикл?

```
for (let i = 0; i = massive.length - 1; i++)
```

вам же надо поменять только 1 и последнее значение, т.е.

```
tmp = massive[0];
massive[0] = massive[massive.length - 1];
massive[massive.length - 1] = tmp;
```

кроме того посмотрите на свой цикл и потом прочитайте про циклы в javascript

```
for (начальные условия; условие продолжения цикла; действия после каждого этапа)
```

у вас условие продолжение цикла

```
i = massive.length - 1
```

учитывая, что изначально `i == 0`, то условие никогда выполняться не будет и цикл не будет выполняться

Да и вообще у вас мешанина кода, у вас должно быть так:

```
if (massive.length > 1) {
    // меняем местами 
}

return massive;
```

и все

P.S.

перед тем как кодить алгоритм удобно его разобрать "на бумаге" по этапам, что каждый этап делает

тогда таких ошибок возникать будет меньше

Answer (score 1):

```
const swap = (array) => {
  const firstCount = array[0];
  if (array.length >= 1) {
      array[0] = array[array.length - 1];
      array[array.length - 1] = firstCount;
    }

  return array;
};
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Цикл вообще здесь не нужен, так же как и не нужен else, кроме прочего функция дает Undifind значение когда массив на вход состоит только из одного значение..

Конечное решение будет такое:

```
export function swap(massive) {
if (massive.length < 2) {
    return massive;
} 
        let tmp = massive[0];
        array[0] = massive[massive.length-1];
        array[massive.length-1] = tmp;
        return massive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
// Массив [arr] как примем, значение может быть любым
const swap = (arr) => {
  // условие (если массив содержит 2 и более элементов)
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    // Переменная которая хранит первое значение массива
    let firstCount = arr[0];
    // Переменная которая хранит последнее значение массива
    let lastCount = arr[arr.length - 1];
    // Присваивание результату - значение массива [arr]
    result = arr;
    // Меняем местами первый и последний элемент массива
    result[result.length - 1] = firstCount;
    result[0] = lastCount;
    // Благодаря значениям переменных
    return result
    // Выводим результат
  } else {
    // Дефолтное значение (если массив пустой или значение < 1)
    return arr
    // Вернуть массив arr
  }
}
```